# Django Session not working between multiple views

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I have a login view which renders a login page for the user to fill.
Once the user submits the login page, a post call is made to another view named home. This home view verifies the user credentials and if successful redirects to another view that renders a new html file.

In settings.py

'django.contrib.sessions' is added to installed apps.
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' is added to MIDDLEWARE.

ISSUE:- I setup a session field in the home view and then from there when the flow gets redirected to the other view, the session field becomes invalid. I cannot give the entire code due to company policy, but I am giving as much as is needed to explain my question.

N.B:- When the Index.html is loaded, the post transaction is through AJAX/jquery from the Index.html file and on success the same index.html file accesses the view XYZ using window.location.href('/XYZ');

ERROR:- KeyError: 'userName'

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

def login( request ):
    return render_to_response('Index.html')

def home( request ):
    login( user );
    request.session['userName'] = "test";
    return HttpResponse( "SUCCESS" )

def XYZ( request ):
    print( request.session['userName'])
    return HttpResponse( "FAILED" )
```

Comment: If you're using Django's own auth framework, you don't need to do this at all; the username is always available via `request.user`. (If you're not using it, you absolutely should be.)

Comment: I am using django's auth framework. But I need to be able to access the session field for logout right? Also, why wouldn't I be able to access session in the above scenario?

Comment: Do you have django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware in your MIDDLEWARE list?

Comment: Yes. I have that added.

Comment: No, why would you need the session for logout? You just do `logout(request)`. But in order to help you we really need to see real code; what you have here wouldn't work at all because `username` is not defined in the `home` view.

Comment: I tried set_test_cookie, it didn't work in the home view either. It worked on login view. The set_test_cookie was done in the index view. does it have anything to do with render or ajax?

Comment: username is defined.. or else for the discussion consider username as any string. I will update my question.

Comment: Btw request.user prints AnonymousUser in the view XYZ even though authenticate and login was done with a particular user name.